# Can a recursive language be uncountable?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, uncountability

Does there exist a recursive language $L$ whose cardinality is uncountable?

I would like to have an explanation whether Turing Machine can encode uncountable languages and whether we can use this to reject the initial question.

Comment: Over finite words and a finite alphabet $\Sigma$, every language is countable, since $\Sigma^*$ is countable...

Comment: so you are saying there is no uncountable language that is recursive?

Comment: Yes. To be uncountable is, literally, a big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Languages are collections of words. Words are finite strings.

As Shaull stated in his comment, *every* language over a finite alphabet is countable. (In fact, every language over a *countable* alphabet is also countable.)

Languages of infinite words, sometimes called $\omega$-languages, are considered in computer science. For example, they are the subject of $\omega$-automata theory. But the Turing machine formalism is about the usual notion of language.

Comment: How do we prove this though?

Comment: what about the language that halts if the first number in a binary number is a 1?

Comment: @revisingcomplexity Shauli gives the proof, assuming that you accept that $|A| \leq |B|$ if $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: I think he assumes that the words are finite. What if L is recursive and uncountable? this would mean that we have infinite strings

Comment: Words *are* finite. This is the entire point. They are finite *by definition*.

Comment: I really don't understand, sorry for the confusion. What about a language whose strings are accepted if the first char is a 1. So we would have a word that is infinite 10000....00... so would this not be a recursive and uncountable language?

Comment: Languages are collections of words. Words are finite strings. The input is always finite. That's how languages are defined in the context of computability. Deal with it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, That was the biggest gap in our knowledge that made us misunderstood most of the concept. Me and other students revising together are really, thankful for your explanation. THANK YOU!