# Is every countably infinite language recursive?

Tags: formal-languages, uncountability

We'll say the alphabet for the languages is finite, say {0,1}.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/can-a-recursive-language-be-uncountable?rq=1
Every language is countable, hence not all countably infinite languages are recursive (since we know there are non recursive languages).

Comment: @Ariel Definitely not a dupe of that question. This question asks "Does every X have property Y?" and the other one is "Are there Y's that don't have property X?"

Comment: Not a duplicate per se, but the answer there explains why every language is countable, which lies at the heart of both questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every language over a finite alphabet is countable so your question is just "is every language recursive?" The undecidability of the halting problem shows that there are non-recursive languages.